# SOAPUI cannot import updated java file in Groovy script

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

I have a testcase in soapui, and in one of its groovy scripts it imports a java file and uses one of the methods in it. (this is a .java file, not a .jar file)

my groovy script

```
import com.aaa.bbb.ccc.myjavafile
myjavafile.method('anystring')
```

I updated my javafile method to take in two inputs method(string,int)

but when I reran my testcase, I get this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.aaa.bbb.ccc.myjavafile.method() is apoplicable for argument types: (java.lang.string,java.lang.Integer).
```

It looks like the changes I made in my java file are not being imported in my script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you start up SoapUI, in the log tab you need to see the message 
"INFO:Adding [C:\Program Files\SmartBear\soapUI-...\bin\ext\myjavafile.jar] to extensions classpath" or SoapUI did not see it!

Make sure you had placed your .jar in the `$SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` directory.